# Integrating D3 into Spotfire

Tags: javascript, d3.js, spotfire

I have a D3 demo code which runs fine using Apache Server. I have the .html, .css and .js file with me for the demo file. I wish to integrate D3 into Spotfire. I also have the csv file that d3 uses.

I have enabled the JavaScript viz within Spotfire web player server. I am not sure how we can integrate this code so that I can run my D3 demo using Spotfire.

Comment: Hey Rikin, what have you tried so far? Are there any specific parts giving you trouble?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have a d3 code (.js, .css, .html) file which runs fine on my local mamp server. However, my goal is to integrate it with Spotfire. I have been reading about JS Visualization package but I am not sure how to load my data file and the js, css and html file using this JS visualization. My data file is in .csv format. Suppose data is an ancestry family tree, with Root is Great Great grandfather as Column1 and its size is determined by Column2; something like, John, 2300; John-Ryan, 100; John-Ryan-Jay, 100, etc. where John is root and Johan-Ryan-Jay are their descendants. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When integrating other visualizations with Spotfire, your first question is whether you want Spotfire in your visualization or your visualization in Spotfire. The distinction is important because these will lead you down dramatically different architectures.

It sounds like you want to put a d3 visualization *in* your Spotfire dashboard using TIBCO's JSVisualization extension. Once you have this extension installed on your Spotfire server, you'll have access to the visualization from the menubar at the top.

The JSViz behaves much like the the textarea, you'll need to open the properties. However, inside, you'll see areas to drop HTML, CSS, and JS code. These all work like you'd expect, except for the JS section. There are 'hooks' that you need to use in order to bring the data into the JS. The data will come from Spotfire as a JSON object, which you will need to unpack.

Comment: The last part is where I get confused. So if you have a successful setup with a viz but you need the data for the widget to reflect the data you are using in a cube/table, how do you connect it to the viz? Do I have to convert my data into JSON so that the viz can use it?